# Yandex api не работает

Tags: javascript, asp.net, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет! Столкнулся с очень странной вещью. Пишу на asp.net, использую yandex api и пытаюсь добавить на карту точки, координаты которых находятся в GridView. Вроде код работает, точки добавляются, но как-то странно... Например такой вот код добавляет не три точки(в GridView3 три строки с точками), а только 2 последних, хотя если смотреть в консоли, то все три точки(Geoobject) были созданы, причем правильно.

```
GrView = document.getElementById('GridView3');
for(var i=1; i<GrView.rows.length;i++)
{
    id = GrView.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML.toString();
    x = GrView.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML.toString();
    y = GrView.rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML.toString();

    myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        // Описание геометрии.
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)]

        },
        // Свойства.
        properties: {           
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 'Infinity',
            iconContent: id
        }
    }, {
        // Опции.
        // Иконка метки будет растягиваться под размер ее содержимого.
        preset: 'twirl#blueStretchyIcon',
        // Метку можно перемещать.
        draggable: false
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);

}
```

А если добавлять например 6,7 или больше точек, то максимум отображаются 4.
Может кто-нибудь знает в чем тут дело?)

Answer (score 0):

1) У вас цикл начинается с 1, а не с 0, это ок?

2) Вы уверены, что ymaps на момент добавления точек инициализирован? У него есть метод

```
ymaps.ready
```

Сделайте

```
ymaps.ready(function () {console.log('ready')});
```

и

```
GrView = document.getElementById('GridView3');
console.log('Start code');
```

И проверьте в какой последовательности будет лог.

Comment: 1) да, цикл именно с 1, так как первая строка в гриде-название
2) Да, он уже инициализирован
`if (document.getElementById("map")) {
        ymaps.ready(mapmaking);
    }`
map-контейнер для карты, mapmaking моя функция в которой из грида считываются точки
Я же говорю, вроде все работает, то есть точки то он считывает, но не все...

Comment: У меня была похожая ситуация, когда я передавал координаты в виде строк. Помогло явное конвертирование в float:

    x = parseFloat(x);

Comment: Так я же так и делаю
`geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)]
`

Comment: Не ну что никто не знает в чем проблема?